# Package - Settings files in a subfolder

Tags: packages, ctan, architecture

I would like to work with a tree structure like the following one, where some settings files are stored in a subfolder.

```
mypack
├── locale
│   ├── english.sty
│   └── french.sty
└── mypack.sty
```

Is it a standard way to do that with packages to be publishoed on CTAN? Or am I a monster that should use a flat structure like the following one for example? :-)

```
mypack
├── mypack-english.sty
├── mypack-french.sty
└── mypack.sty
```

Comment: As I understand it, CTAN want a flat structure. That doesn't mean the package has to be installed that way. Though file names like `english` are likely to be problematic.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right... I've updated my question.

Comment: even if the files are in a subfolder they should have globally unique names so `locale/mypack-english.sty `

Comment: if you add `mypack/locale/english.sty` to a standard texlive tree you would break babel (or babel would break your package) depending on random order of the file name cache.

Comment: OK. I am not a criminal. ;-) I will use `locale/mypack-english.cfg` and an `\input` command. But I have seen that using something like `\input{../mypack/locale/english.sty}` in `mypack.sty` should be prohibited for security reasons... Why?

Comment: you can just use `\input{mypack-english.sty}` (although I would not use `.sty` if it is onput rather than RequirePackage)  there is no advantage to adding `local/` to the `\input` path.

Comment: `\input{../mypack/locale/english.sty}` is accessing files not in the directory below the current working directory of the tex process. There is an option to ban that as a site setting in texmf.cnf (although by default readingbut not writing is allowed)  note the `..` is not relative to your package file, it is relative to the tex process on the end users machine

Comment: Thanks for all. I will adapt my coding process.

Comment: Note that if a file is in a standard location, it doesn't matter whether it is in a subdirectory or not. That's why using `mypackage/locale/english.sty` will cause trouble (and will not make it into TeX distributions): because `\usepackage{english}` will still find it. That's why the file name needs to be unique rather than just the path.

Comment: So it's a sort of flat virtual directory that's used. I'll make a note of it and keep it in mind.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle One last question. Are configuration files, tree structures and imports without `..` accepted by `TeX`?

Comment: well they are accepted in the sense that they are just input files but the filenames have to be globally unique so they don't really help, and paths are confusing as they are always relative to where the end user started tex, not to the current file, so you can not have a package in a file `latex/mypackage/mypackage.sty` that directly refers to a subdirectory of `mypackage`. if you do `\input(locale/foo.def}` it may input `latex/mypackage/locale/foo.def` but only by searching the entire tex path again for any file with a path ending in that form.

Comment: see for example `[12pt]` option tells `article.cls` to load `size12.clo`  it does `\input{size10.clo}` which works, but not because that file is in the same directory as `article.cls` it does a full search of TEXINPUTS and happens to find a file ein the same directory because the filename is globally unique and found on the same path as `article.cls`

Comment: Thank you. All this is clearer for me.